# valueUpdate event for change in select option

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, typescript

I'm trying to create an editable combo box.
This is the HTML I wrote:

```
<select data-bind='options: possibleOptions, value: selectedOption' onchange='this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value'></select>
<input type='text' name='format' data-bind='value: selectedOption, valueUpdate:[\"afterkeydown\", \"click\", \"input\", \"change\"]' />
```

with the help of http://jsfiddle.net/nwH8A/. 
So what's happening is that the selectedOption updates properly when I enter text input manually. But when I choose an option from the drop down list(possibleOptions), the value of selectedOption does not update unless I click on the text box. Basically what I am trying to do is allow the user to enter text manually as well as choose from the drop down list and update the value of selectedOption correspondingly.

Is there any event that I need to add to the list of valueUpdate events or is there some other way to accomplish the result?

I'm working in a typescript file.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using an `event` data binding instead of the `onchange` trigger property. Definitely don't mess with `this.value`.

Comment: It'll be easier to play with if you add KO to your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question... Try this:

```
 function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.possibleOptions = ko.observableArray([ { text: '1', value: '1' }, { text: '2', value: '2' } ]);
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable();

    self.selectedOption.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.possibleOptions.push({ text: newValue, value: newValue });
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: possibleOptions, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value: selectedOption">

</select>

<input type="text" name="format" data-bind="value: selectedOption" />
```

To see this working: https://jsfiddle.net/q6ov7r59/3/

Comment: What I want is somewhat like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/krypt/q6ov7r59/1/). I want to change the value of selectedOption if any of the 2 happen: 1) selected option changes 2)some text is entered. In this fiddle, selectedOption is not updated when text is entered. What do I do for that?